# Would it be dangerous to send all the wp_options to javascript file?

Tags: security, options

I've noticed that wordpress allows me to send the wordpress options to javascript via wp_localize_script:

```
wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-plugin-script', 'wp_options', wp_load_alloptions() );
```

This way, my javascript can access different settings such as what day the week start on and what date format the user has chosen.

Are there any risks, sending all the options as a variable to js, or is this okay? I've noticed that options such as "logged_in_key" and "logged_in_salt" becomes available in the front end too.

My gut tells me that this is bad practice - securitywise ? But I wanted to hear from someone who knows more about security in wordpress.

Thanks.

Malthe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a *really* bad idea. Just send what you need, exposing all this data publicly opens a lot (and some more) attack vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trust your gut, it's bad practice, and is certainly a security risk.

Forget salt keys. Think of all the plugins that store local & 3rd party credentials. They (almost) always store it in the options table. And now I (or anyone else) has access to it.